# How to graph math in c#?

Tags: c#, graph

Given the following graph as example:
[image]

Since its just an example I would make my custom graph input like this:
[image]

I would like to know the shortest and the longest way from A to E or at least what entered like this:

A-B-D-E 6

Sadly I have no idea how to start a graph math like this. Maybe List/Point. I am sure i will need array or at least something i can put the values.

Comment: Do you have a *specific* problem that you want help with? Specific questions are best on a Q&A forum like this.

Comment: Are you familiar with object oriented programing?

Comment: Not really, but if the way is it, then i wont back off.

Comment: Did you try googling anything? These seem like what you are trying to do https://letmetutoryou.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/shortest-path-with-dijkstra-and-c/ http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Dijkstra.aspx

Comment: This Q will be closed because it is too broad. And you will need _A*_ algorithm or _Dijkstra_.

Comment: Okay, at least I've got a start point, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to know the Dijkstra's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Another option is to use a third party tool. I'm a developer for a company that makes one of those and you can do what you need with a single method call: http://www.mindfusion.eu/onlinehelp/flowchartnet/index.htm?T_MindFusion_Diagramming_PathFinder_Members.htm